# WifiDirect Catching Discover(Android4.x)

Tags: android

I am trying `catch` a Discover-command of `WifiDirect` on Android4.0.But BroadcastReceiver can not catch it Only cathcing

- WIFI_P2P_CONNECTION_CHANGED_ACTION
- WIFI_P2P_PEERS_CHANGED_ACTION
- WIFI_P2P_STATE_CHANGED_ACTION
- WIFI_P2P_THIS_DEVICE_CHANGED_ACTION

How to catch Discover-command of `WifiDirect`?